# SSIS condition to replace #Name? and display no value

Tags: ssis, conditional-split

When I run my SSIS package, I receive a #Name? in a column cells where no value is present, so I created a Conditional Split using the following condition, ISNULL(columnname) || LEN(columnname) == 0.

The customer prefers that the column cell be empty instead of displaying a 0. When I replace the 0 with  ? or “ ”, the conditional split does not recognize the character.

What do I need to do to make the column cell appear empty when there is no value returned.

Thanks for any assistance that can be given.

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: I am guessing it is a flat file. Check the box on the source of data flow that "keeps nulls"

Comment: Also you can't replace the number 0 with a string.

Comment: The source is a SharePoint list.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Derived Column and convert it to NULL.

So, if you're getting a string of "#Name?" you could use:

```
columnname == "#Name?" ? NULL(DT_WSTR, 50) : columnname
```

Or if you're actually getting the value 0 you could use:

```
columnname == 0 ? NULL(DT_I4) : columnname
```

Comment: No problem :) - please mark the answer as correct if it is working.